How to create a docker container with a hard limit on the amount of disc space it can use with ext4 filesystem
As outlined here: https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/container/run/#storage-opt from How to limit Docker filesystem space available to container(s) there's a --storage-opt flag that can be used to limit the size of a container.
The error raised from:
docker run --rm -it  --storage-opt size=120G alpine:latest sh

Is:
docker: Error response from daemon: --storage-opt is supported only for overlay over xfs with 'pquota' mount option.

Looking at docker run --help as instructed doesn't help that much.
So my question is - when using an ext4 filesystem how can I create a docker container with a hard limit in the amount of disc space that it can use? Eg - I would like to be able to set the disc space to 100M, then run dd if=/dev/zero of=test_file bs=20M count=15 and have it fail due to disc space limits (or whatever it raises).

If you need per-container storage limits, you will need to use a storage driver that supports that feature. As you have already discovered, you can do that using the overlay driver if you have /var/lib/docker on XFS. While it looks like ext4 also has support for "project quotas" ("pquota"), it doesn't look as if Docker has implemented support for that feature.
Alternatively, the btrfs and zfs storage drivers both appear to support size storage option.

Thanks - you mention btrfs and zfs but i'm unsure what steps I would take to make use of them? Does this require me uninstalling / reinstalling docker or is it possible for me to pass some sort of flag to a docker run command?

Those are both different Linux filesystems. You would need to format a disk/partition/other block device and mount it onto /var/lib/docker.

Thanks - I don't mean to seem lazy but I'm not familiar with how I would go about doing this - are you able to give any more guidance please? I don't know why I'd use btrfs over zfs, a google seems to suggest zfs is generally better? Though docker docs seem less sure (https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/zfs-driver/) so i don't know. Either way - how would I go about setting this up in order to answer the original question? Is that document I linked (/storagedriver/zfs-driver) a suitable guide? I haven't really messed with this stuff before :)

This is all veering off topic for stackoverflow (and away from the topic of your question). Moving to overlay + XFS is probably simplest (because it will most closely resemble you're existing configuration). If you want to learn about btrs or ZFS, I would suggest setting a test environment and working them there until you feel comfortable managing them before you build a service on top of them.

What's it on topic for? I'll post there. It's not away from the question, I guess I'd expect an answer to the question to provide code which solves the question rather than summarising the storage drivers that do support it. Perhaps I should have made that clearer in the question. Thanks.
